# Unable to import factor analyzer Spyder 3.3.6 Python via Conda

Tags: python, spyder, multivariate-testing

I'm attempting to import factor_analyzer into Spyder and am receiving:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'

```
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
```

AND

```
pip install factor_analyzer
```

Results:

```
from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-ce9a8a607260>", line 1, in <module>
    from factor_analyzer import FactorAnalyzer

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'factor_analyzer'




pip install factor_analyzer
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
'C:\Users\J' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: How come you are using such an old Python version?

Comment: Spyder version 3.3.6

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to fix this problem.